# Nearly solved my issue with using libcurl in dev C++, one final hitch. (libcurl.dll is missing)

Tags: c, libcurl, static-linking, dev-c++

I previously asked a question concerning libcurl. I've managed to find an answer to it on my own, and will be glad to share how I solved the issue, as soon as I'm sure it worked. Here's the thing, previous to this, the linker would throw a fit when I tried to compile, and with a bit of searching and trial and error, I found that including this:

```
-I curl\include 
-L curl\lib 
-lws2_32 
-lwldap32
```

into the linker made sure that the program compiled.
The issue is, that once the program compiles, running it returns the error:
The program can't start because libcurl.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Here's my code, though I doubt its relevant:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    CURLcode ret;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed creating CURL easy handle!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Attempt to get Facebook*/
    ret = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com");
    if (ret != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting http://www.google.com: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting http://www.google.com: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are several possible answers.  One would be simply to copy libcurl.dll into the same directory as the `.exe`.  Windows should find it there.

Comment: For some reason, it does [not find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) the dll mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You have succesfully linked the compiler to the static library of `libcurl`. However when you execute the program It tries to find the `.ddl` for `libcurl` and is unable to find it at the directories it searches. Usually this is the directory you run the application from. Try putting the `.dll` at that location and see if that helps.

Comment: Done so, but the program now refuses to run anyway, throwing the error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application. I suspect the issue may be that the library I'm using may not be compatible with Dev C++, I'll try recompiling the source code.